# Bulk uploading and linking images for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, image, csv, woocommerce, bulk-import

I'm planning out how to bulk upload a few thousand products to WooCommerce, and I don't know how to proceed with images. Is there a better way than uploading them all and then manually copying the URL from the media gallery to my CSV?

Is it possible to name the images in such a way that they get recognized and automatically associated to the corresponding product?

What about gallery images, should they be named the same with a number at the end?

I'm building the site locally for now and the images are on my computer, what will happen with the images when I host it online? Thank you for your help!

PS: I know there are plugins that do this, but I'm looking for a non-plugin alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt option in WooCommerce to import products, you can use that.